# How to resolve deep penetration of nodes in general contact?

Tags: abaqus

I've been running a simulation of thermal expansion. Two parts are defined and conected via TIE. one of the parts is surrouneded by a fixed (ENCASTRE) membrane surface, and the two are defined in general contact as pairs.
During thermal expansion I found the following warning:
**"Some nodes involved in general contact have penetrated their  tracked faces by more than 50.000 percent of the typical element dimension in the general contact domain."**
The contact seemed to be ignored, as there is a deep penetration of the internal part through the outer membrane surface, despite the high density of the outer surface mesh.
The penetration is not only in the TIE area, but scatered all across.
Defining a Thickness surface to the parts in contact was impractical.

## More info:

Abaqus version: 2017 Explicit.

### Contact:

Hard contact

```
constraint enforcement method -
(Normal) Default. Allow separation after contact,
(Tangential) Fricttionless. 0;
```

### Material properties:

#### Inner part:

```
Density 1e-09, Hyperelastic, neo hooke, moduli=INSTANTANEOUS values:200.,0.
Viscoelastic, time=RELAXATION TEST DATA, nmax=5
Expansion - alpha 0.001
```

#### Outer part:

```
  Density 1e-09, Elastic  9000, 0.29
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In questions like this one, a small sketch can be of help if you think that boundary conditions have an important influence. Have you checked the consistency of units? Did you use general contact or contact pairs? Try another one. Try to have a small gap between surfaces so they can be placed in contact during simulation at a specified simulation step.

Comment: There could be a lot of things that can result in such behaviour. You should perform some study/sensitivities by yourself and come here with a clear technical question. "Why this doesn't work" is too vague especially for this domain.